# resetting to first view controller when tabbaritem is selected

Tags: iphone

I have a tab bar with 3 items.  Each points to a `UINavigationController`.   Each `UINavigationController` has several `viewControllers` beneath.   I'm wanting to reset back to the first controller in the navigation when any tab bar item is pressed.

I've specified my `TabBarController` implementation as a `delegate`

`self.delegate = self` and my method below (running in my `TabBarController` implementation works returning `UINavigationControllers`.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"%@", viewController);
}
```

With the log file showing e.g.

```
UINavigationController: 0x8a31a90>2012-12-31 02:16:40.035 Demo[6142:c07]
```

when I try `popToRootViewController` or `popViewController` within this method it doesn't seem to work.  I don't get any errors but my `viewControllers` don't reset. It seems like I've made a really basic error here but I can't tell what.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"%@", viewController);
    [self.navigationController  popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to popToRootViewController on the navigationController (viewcontroller)  - not the TabViewController (self).

```
[viewController  popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: What @damon said, except you'll have to cast the viewController first: [(UINavigationController *)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: Excellent, thanks Aky and damon.  Yes  [(UINavigationController *)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; works great.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help. I had a lot of trouble getting this to work and found that I needed to do the following:

In root view controller (first view app comes to), add a delegate in the .h file.

```
@interface MGMProductsViewController : UIViewController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

Add the below code to viewDidLoad in root view controller (.m file).

```
[self.tabBarController setDelegate:self];
```

Override method in root view controller (.m file) with the below.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController  
{  
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
        [(UINavigationController*)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

I can't attribute this to anyone as I couldn't find the appropriate code again. I think I pieced it together from a few places though the '[self.tabBarController setDelegate:self]' looked to be the key to it working for me.

Good luck.